# How to select td when you know th text with jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table containing rows with exactly one th and one td like this:

```
<tr>
  <th>Phone Number</th>
  <td>555-555-1212</td>
</tr>
```

I need to select the td cell (and replace the html) by using the th text "Phone Number".  I can get the th cell with

```
$('th:contains("Phone Number")')
```

but I can't figure out how to select the corresponding td cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('th:contains("Phone Number")').next('td');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('th:contains("Phone Number")').next("td")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var html = "some html";  
  $('th:contains("Phone Number")').next('td').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

$("th:contains('Phone Number')").siblings("td");

You can also use this if you have only one sibling of th otherwise next() is best.